# Maximum sum of non-consecutive elements of an array

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

> You are given a list of houses on a street, with the numeric value
>   representing the amount of money stashed away in each house.
>
> Write a method to find the maximum amount of money you can steal. You
>   cannot steal from any two adjacent houses, otherwise you will be
>   caught! Use Dynamic Programming!
>
> Examples:
>
> - `robbery([60, 50, 20, 32, 20, 50])` → `142`
> - `robbery([40, 25, 25, 30])` → `70`

I would like to ask for a review of the following solution.

```
def robbery(amounts):
    amounts = iter(amounts)
    prev, total = 0, next(amounts, 0)
    for x in amounts: prev, total = total, max(total, prev + x)
    return total
```

Here's my code on Gist:
https://gist.github.com/Jeffchiucp/6dbd481ce4bc208e6da68bc8e920bf3f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithm is conceptually fine: it's simple and it works.

I don't like the use of `iter()` and `next()`, though.  When you write `for x in amounts`, that will already treat `amounts` as an iterator.  The only benefit you get from an explicit `amount = iter(amounts)`, then, is the ability to write `next(amounts, 0)`.  And the only reason for writing `next(amounts, 0)` is to handle the special case where the input is an empty list.  You could just as well handle that by pretending that there is always another leading house with 0 money.

```
def robbery(amounts):
    prev, total = 0, 0
    for amount in amounts:
        prev, total = total, max(total, prev + amount)
    return total
```

The `for` loop would be better written with the conventional indentation.